# How to add a column after using python groupby if the function is also a custom function?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am stuck on what is probably a very simple problem. My data looks something like this:

| id_not_unique | datetime | seconds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111111 | 2020-08-26 15:44:58 | 122 |
| 111111111 | 2020-08-28 15:33:45 | 34 |
| 222222222 | 2020-07-12 11:21:09 | 26 |
| 222222222 | 2019-04-21 14:22:42 | 57 |

So I want to group by id_not_unique and then add a new column called time that is just finding the minimum datetime in the group and then return the corresponding seconds. So the result would look something like:

| id_not_unique | time |
| --- | --- |
| 111111111 | 122 |
| 222222222 | 57 |

I have tried this:

```
def wait_first_call(df):
    min_time = min(df['datetime'])

    idx = df.index[df.datetime == min_time]
    
    first_time = df['seconds'].iloc[idx]
    
    return first_time
```

then

```
df.groupby(['id_not_unique']).apply(wait_first_call)
```

But I keep getting an "IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds". So I am not understanding why I am getting this error -- I thought the apply function took each group as a dataframe and applies the function to this group?

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `.loc` in place of `.iloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code:

1. `.iloc` is for indexing using the row_number, column_number. You
   should not use index in `.iloc`, If one of your index is greater
   than the number of rows in the dataframe then it will throw error.
   That's what is happening in your case. You can resolve this error
   by using `.loc` which takes index.
2. Use `df['datetime'].idxmin()` to get the index corresponding to minimum `b`
   value. Problem with `df.index[df.datetime == min_time]` is that it
   returns a list of indices even if there is only one match `(format: Index([ind])` and when you use this to index dataframe as in
   `df['seconds'].loc[idx]`, it gives you a series which we don't need.

Use this code snippet:

```
def wait_first_call(df):
      idx = df['datetime'].idxmin()
      first_time = df['seconds'].loc[idx]
      return pd.Series({'time': first_time}, index = ['time'])

df.groupby(['id_not_unique'], as_index = False).apply(wait_first_call)
```

**Update**:  Without Using `.apply`

I have found apply to be usually slow and hence I am posting another approach to solve:

First get the min_idx for each group in another column.

```
df['min_idx'] = (df.groupby('id_not_unique')['datetime']
                 .transform(lambda x: x.idxmin()))
```

Now Filter the dataframe where index is eq to min index.

```
 new_df = (df[df.index == df.min_idx]
             [['id_not_unique', 'seconds']]
             .rename(columns = {'seconds': 'time'}))
```

Comment: A little bit unrelated, but for this solution in particular, if I were to add another column doing some other manipulation, would I add the code in wait_first_call and then return another pd.Series({'new_col': something}) ?

Comment: Yes. return `pd.Series({'time': first_time, 'new_col': value}, index = ['time', 'new_col'])`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with remove column `datetime` with `rename`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df = (df.sort_values(['id_not_unique','datetime'])
        .drop_duplicates('id_not_unique')
        .drop('datetime', axis=1)
        .rename(columns = {'seconds': 'time'}))
print (df)
   id_not_unique     time
0      111111111      122
3      222222222       57
```

Or use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for index by minimal `datetime` and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df = (df.loc[df.groupby('id_not_unique')['datetime'].idxmin()]
       .drop('datetime', axis=1)
       .rename(columns = {'seconds': 'time'}))
print (df)
   id_not_unique     time
0      111111111      122
3      222222222       57
```